# Is it safe to call sc_fifo::nb_write() from a SC_THREAD process?

Tags: systemc

I am converting some of my code from a SC_THREAD to a SC_METHOD.  My question is, do I need to stop using the sc_fifo class?  I realize an SC_METHOD should not call sc_fifo.write() because this uses a wait call which is not allowed for functions that cannot be suspended.  However, sc_fifo provides non-blocking versions of various functions and potentially I could use these instead.  Some of the documentation I've read indicates you should never use sc_fifo from a SC_METHOD at all but provided no justification.

Here is a sample of code I am currently using.

```
class Example : public sc_module {
public:
        sc_fifo<int> myFifo;
        sc_in<bool> clock_in;

        SC_HAS_PROCESS(Example);

        // constructor
        Example(sc_module_name name) : sc_module(name) {
                SC_METHOD(read);
                        sensitive << clock_in;
        }

        void read() {
                int value = -1;
                bool success = myFifo.nb_read(value);
                if (success) { cout << "Read value " << value << endl; }
                else { cout << "No read done but that's okay." << endl; }
        }

};

int sc_main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        sc_clock clock("clock");
        Example example("example");
        example.clock_in(clock);
        sc_start(10, SC_NS);
        return 0;
}
```

This throws no errors even though I am calling an sc_fifo function from a SC_METHOD.  Is it bad policy to use nb_read() from inside a SC_METHOD?  If so why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sc_fifo non-blocking calls from SC_METHOD should be fine.
I have not found any place in standard manual that prohibits it.

Answer (score 0):

Neither nb_read, nor nb_write, as their names suggest, call wait internally so it's fine to use them from an SC_METHOD.

While your example code works, it's rather inefficient when things are put into the fifo infrequently.  If you want your code to be more event driven, you could make the SC_METHOD sensitive to sc_fifo.data_written_event(); then it will only be called when something is actually written to the fifo (though it's still a good idea to check that nb_read returns true in case something else pulled from the same fifo).  Of course, this would skip your "No read done but that's okay." prints.

Also, I think the title of your question probably meant to ask about calling nb_write from SC_METHOD rather than SC_THREAD.